# Couldn't figure out why I get this error: "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level" on every line of code I write

Tags: python

This is a problem I faced in so many cases and I just can't figure out what the problem is. Below is an example code, but this happens to me every time I write an if/else condition or anything else indented right.

```
def amplify(num):
  lst = []
  for i in range(1,num+1):
    if i%4 == 0:
      lst.append(i*10)
    else:
      lst.append(i)
  return lst
```

Error:

> else: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: You are mixing spaces and tabs. Don't do that. Keep to spaces (or tabs) but not both.

Comment: Depending on your IDE/editor, you might be able to configure it such that e.g. tabs are replaced by spaces automatically, such that the problem does not occur again.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments, this error is due to mixing tabs and spaces. If you don't know how to convert tabs to spaces in you IDE, [this website](https://tabstospaces.com/) should do the thing for you. Just paste your code and click `convert tabs to spaces`.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-indenting them with the standard [4 spaces](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwivy4ed5P7pAhWlSjABHTnGAQYQFjAEegQIDRAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.python.org%2Fdev%2Fpeps%2Fpep-0008%2F&usg=AOvVaw0xCyNbAyoecmbLoILApdrP), like so:

```
def amplify(num):
    lst = []
    for i in range(1,num+1):
        if i%4 == 0:
            lst.append(i*10)
        else:
            lst.append(i)
    return lst
```